# Mongo:. How to get unique rows

Tags: mongodb

I have the following object and would like to get all record that has a keyword and deviceID.

There could be multiple object with same deviceID. I would like last entry for each Device ID

```
{
  search:{
     keyword:"_"
   },
  dateCreated:"",
  device:[{
    deviceID:"_"
  }],

}
```

example

```
{
  search:{
     keyword:"FL"
   },
  dateCreated:"01/01/2017",
  device:[{
    deviceID:"1"
  }],

}

{
  search:{
     keyword:"ATL"
   },
  dateCreated:"01/02/2017",
  device:[{
    deviceID:"1"
  }],

}
{
  search:{
     keyword:"GA"
   },
  dateCreated:"01/03/2017",
  device:[{
    deviceID:"2"
  }],

}
```

The query should return

```
{
  search:{
     keyword:"ATL"
   },
  dateCreated:"01/02/2017",
  device:[{
    deviceID:"1"
  }],

}
{
  search:{
     keyword:"GA"
   },
  dateCreated:"01/03/2017",
  device:[{
    deviceID:"2"
  }],

}
```

Comment: ```device:[{ deviceID:"2"}],``` why do you store deviceID in array of devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not achieve that using "dateCreated",first you need to convert "dateCreated" Column in date format(in context to mongo ISO date). After that, you can run following for achieving the last entry as mentioned in your question

```
db.abc.aggregate([
{
"$unwind": "$device"
 },
 {$group: {
   _id: "$device",
   search: {
     "$max": "$search"
   },
   dateCreated: {
     "$max": "$dateCreated"
   }
 }
 }
])
```

and if you are looking for the same Json format then you can project this query,

```
db.abc.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$device"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$device",
      device: {
        "$push": "$device"
      },
      search: {
        "$max": "$search"
      },
      dateCreated: {
        "$max": "$dateCreated"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      search: 1,
      dateCreated: 1,
      device: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `$elemMatch`:

```
db.collection.find({device: {$elemMatch: {deviceID:'1')}});
```

`$elemMatch` allows you to match more than one component within the same array element.

Read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

Answer (score 0):

iam not understand exactly what you mean but here iam giving one solution what i understood check it once

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:"$search.keyword",dateCreated:{$last:"$dateCreated"},device:{$last:"$device"}}},{$match:{"device.deviceID":{$ne:null}}}
])
```

here iam grouping by search keyword if you want you can group by both search keyword and device and including last device by using $last and finally matching device not equal to null